# How can I write to a buffer (void pointer)?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I want to write in 2 chars and a bit vector (uint64_t) to a file, but I first have to write them all to a buffer. Then the buffer will be written to the file. How should I write these 3 variables into a buffer (void pointer) so that all can be contained within one (void pointer) variable.

For example I want to write

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';
uint64_t c = 0x0000111100001111;
```

into

```
void *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*2+sizeof(uint64_t));
```

Then write that into a file using

```
write(fd, buffer, sizeof(char)*2+sizeof(uint64_t));
```

Comment: You could convert that hex into a char array and then put all the data into a char array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the (almost*) completely safe way of doing it:

```
uint8_t *buffer = malloc(2 + sizeof(uint64_t));
buffer[0] = a;
buffer[1] = b;
memcpy(buffer + 2, &c, sizeof(c));
```

You might be tempted to do something like `*(uint64_t *)(buffer + 2) = c;` but that's not portable due to alignment restrictions.

Note that `sizeof(char) == 1`, per definition in the C standard.

(*) I've assumed 8-bit `char`, which is nearly, but not entirely universal; on a platform with 16-bit `char`, use `memcpy` for `a` and `b` as well.

Comment: Why is a uint8_t pointer type used instead of a void type for buffer?

Comment: If you use `char` instead of `uint8_t`, will not it be portable?

Comment: I think when you write `(uint64_t *)(buffer + 2) = c;` you mean either `*(uint64_t *)(buffer + 2) = c;` or `(uint64_t *)(buffer + 2)[0] = c;`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can allways put the data into a buffer like this:

```
void *buffer = malloc(size_of_buffer);
char *ch = buffer;
*pos++ = a;
*pos++ = b;
*(uint64_t*)(pos) = c
```

Or use memcpy like cnicutar suggests. However, I would think it's a lot easier and less error prone to just write each element to the file one at the time:

```
write(fd, &a, sizeof a);
write(fd, &b, sizeof b);
write(fd, &c, sizeof c);
```

Beware of endian issues.